# asp.net chart read from aspx.cs file with custom query from sql server

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, sql-server, visual-studio

I have a chart in asp.net web form page. i want to fill it with a custom query created by joining two variables from the same sql table.

Here is the code (query):

```
String year2 = Convert.ToString(dropDownStartYear.Text);
String month2 = Convert.ToString(dropDownMonth2.Text);
String day2 = Convert.ToString(dropDownDay2.Text);
String hour2 = Convert.ToString(dropDownHour2.Text);
String minute2 = Convert.ToString(dropDownMinute2.Text);

String year3 = Convert.ToString(dropdownYear3.Text);
String month3 = Convert.ToString(dropDownMonth3.Text);
String day3 = Convert.ToString(dropDownDay3.Text);
String hour3 = Convert.ToString(dropDownHour3.Text);
String minute3 = Convert.ToString(dropDownMinute3.Text);

SqlConnection connection = ConnectionManager.getConnection();
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
cmd.Connection = connection;
cmd.CommandText = "SELECT id, temperature, year, month, day , hour, minu from datab where year = @year and month=@month and day=@day and hour=@hour and minu=@minute ; ";
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@year", year2);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@month", month2);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@day", day2);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@hour", hour2);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@minute", minute2);

SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

while (reader.Read())
{

}
```

where i want to select a start date and time (year, month, day, hour, minute) from a table in sql server and also select an end date with same variables.
then i want to draw the "temperature" that varies from the start time to the end time.

any help there?

Comment: So what does or doesn't this do?

Comment: where do i put the code do display the chart

Comment: This seems to be two separate questions. Answers below address building the query. Do you have a control for your chart on the .aspx page?

Answer (score 1):

Try this query, building `DateTime` objects from the date parts in the input and stored in your table. That should make it easier to compare and restrict your return values by the selected input values:

```
cmd.CommandText = @"select [id], [temperature], [year], [month], [day], [hour], [minu] 
from datab
where DATETIMEFROMPARTS([year], [month], [day], [hour], [minu], 0, 0) 
between DATETIMEFROMPARTS(@year2, @month2, @day2, @hour2, @minute2, 0, 0) 
and DATETIMEFROMPARTS(@year3, @month3, @day3, @hour3, @minute3, 0, 0)";

// beginning of date range
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@year2", year2);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@month2", month2);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@day2", day2);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@hour2", hour2);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@minute2", minute2);

// end of date range
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@year3", year3);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@month3", month3);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@day3", day3);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@hour3", hour3);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@minute3", minute3);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this query...

```
    cmd.CommandText = "SELECT id, temperature, year, month, day , hour, minu from datab 
where CONVERT ( datetime , cast(year as varchar)+'-'+cast(month as varchar)+'-'+cast(day as varchar)+' '+cast(hour as varchar)+':'+cast(minute as varchar)+':'+'00' , 20) >= CONVERT ( datetime , @yearfrom+'-'+@monthFrom+'-'+@dayFrom+' '+@hourFrom+':'+@minuteFrom+':'+'00' , 20)
and CONVERT ( datetime , cast(year as varchar)+'-'+cast(month as varchar)+'-'+cast(day as varchar)+' '+cast(hour as varchar)+':'+cast(minute as varchar)+':'+'00' , 20) <= CONVERT ( datetime , @yearTo+'-'+@monthTo+'-'+@dayTo+' '+@hourTo+':'+@minuteTo+':'+'00' , 20);";
```

Comment: where do i put it exactly?

Comment: You can use code suggested by Poosh in answer which is short  in code

Comment: so where do i put it exactly?

Comment: @MHDBKT, this is a replacement for your current SQL command text. You would just put it in place of your current `cmd.CommandText` initialization.